# zk nested forEach

Tags: foreach, nested, zk, zul

I have following structure to display in zul file and got List of clinic object from Java controller.

I tried several zk components in zul with no luck. What component should I use with a `forEach`?

- ListBox
- ListItem
- Grid

**Here is structure need to display :**

```
For each clinic
{ 
    For each clinic.location 
    { 
        For each (clinic.location.provider) 
        { 
            Output (provider display name) 
        } 
        Output (clinic name) 
        Output (clinic.location address) 
        Output (clinic.locatoin telephone number) 
        Output (clinic.web address)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the answer given by Darius, here is an example of how to use a `<Grid>`  with a `<rows>` component

```
<?page title="Result"?>
<zk>
    <window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('fully.qualified.viewmodel.classname')"
        title="Result Window" border="normal" >
        <div>
            <grid>
                <rows>
                    <row>
                        <listbox model="@bind(vm.listname)">
                            <listhead>
                                <listheader label="Item Name"
                                    style="text-align:center;">
                                </listheader>
                                <listheader label="Attribute Value"
                                    style="text-align:center;">
                                </listheader>
                                <listheader label="Qualifier Value"
                                    style="text-align:center;">
                                </listheader>
                            </listhead>
                            <template name="model" var="item">
                                <listitem value="${item }">
                                    <listcell label="@load(item.name)"
                                        style="text-align:center;">

                                    </listcell>
                                    <listcell
                                        style="text-align:center;">
                                        <textbox
                                            value="@bind(item.attributeValue)"
                                            style="text-align:center;" />

                                    </listcell>
                                    <listcell
                                        label="@load(item.qualifierValue)"
                                        style="text-align:center;">
                                    </listcell>
                                </listitem>
                            </template>
                        </listbox>
                    </row>
                </rows>
            </grid>
        </div>

    </window>
</zk>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Listbox or a Grid.

- If you use a Listbox, it will contain Listitem objects
- If you use a Grid, it will contain a Rows object, which will contain Row objects

To the Listitem or the Row, you will add other components: the simplest would be Label objects

I notice you have an inner table of providers. For these, you will probably need a nested Grid or Listbox. You could also use ZK's Detail component. it would allow you to expand in order to see the inner table.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways how to achieve this

- including separate zul file to template row, whitch will contain a grid with separate view model - this style you can have shown all nested grid at once ,but it should and it will have performance issiues with larger ammout of data(because count of rows == count of viewmodels of nested grids)
- include nested grid with own template ,and data model as parameter of view model,and show this grid on demand(button click,row click etc)  - this is bether way in case of no performance issues,but you will be able to show only one nested grid at time

Final words - **just don´t**

Nesting a grid to grid is a very bad design,because it is incredibly hard to render this,and it is only usable for small data. The best way to do this,in my opinion is to create two separate grids,side by side,and show adition data on in second grid,after a click on row in first grid. This way you can achieve very fast gui with no performance issiues,ever with a lot of data. Another way is to create a popup on grid row,whitch will show additional data,a it is also a lot bether for your performance.